# is it possible to trigger jqueryui dialog from the URL?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a login page, http://www.mydomain.com/login

now I want to make this login page as a dialog, form will be loaded to the dialog box.

when user goes to the backend, if they are not authenticated, they will be redirect to

http://www.mydomain.com/?action=login

how do i check the querystring using jquery and trigger the dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

I often use this function to get the querystring, you use it like this:

```
function querySt(ji) {
    hu = window.location.search.substring(1);
    gy = hu.split("&");
    for (i = 0; i < gy.length; i++) {
        ft = gy[i].split("=");
        if (ft[0] == ji) {
            return ft[1];
        }
    }
    return ""
}

// Your code
var action = querySt("action"); // Will say login if its provied
if(action!=""){
 // Trig dialog
}
```